# KsqlRestClient.makeKsqlRequest("RUN SCRIPT ...") doesn't work without filling ksql.schema.file.content with the script content yourself

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, ksqldb

In my Scala application, I am trying to tell my KSQL Server that it should execute the `RUN SCRIPT <script>` command, using the `KsqlRestClient.makeKsqlRequest(String ksql)` function. Every time I tried it, nothing happened, even though the response was successful, so I started debugging, where I saw that the response was a success but it also returned some kind of error that the property **ksql.schema.file.content** was empty.

Since I did not find any documentation as to what to fill this property with, I tried some things and eventually found out that if you fill this property with the contents of your .sql file, the run script command works.

Does anybody know if and with what ksql.schema.file.content should normally be filled and/or if the way I am using it is how your supposed to execute a script in KSQL from a Scala application. I already copy and pasted the text from the makeKsqlRequest into the KSQL CLI and everything worked fine, so there should be no error with that.

Comment: KSQL's REST API is currently undocumented by design, since it's not currently supported and may change. It's on the roadmap to document and fully support in the future though. Also check out the [Confluent Community Slack group](https://slackpass.io/confluentcommunity) where you may find other people trying to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Github issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/304) tracking the fact that the RESTful API is not documented / supported yet, (as of March 2018).

It sounds like this is something you may want to add a `+1` too.

Comment: It's documented now, and has roughly always been "supported" - https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/304#issuecomment-389088783